# from javascript to php to javascript -need correction

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

im making something and this code isnt working

```
<script src='jq.js'></script>
<script>
function getURLParameter(name) {
    return decodeURI(
        (RegExp(name + '=' + '(.+?)(&|$)').exec(location.search)||[,null])[1]
    );
}

nick = getURLParameter('kagNick')
</script>
<?php
$url = "https://api.kag2d.com/player/"+nick+"/status";
$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$result = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
?>

<script>
status = $result.split("\n")
if(status[4].indexOf("true,") != -1)
    document.write("gold player")
</script>
```

What is wrong with the code?
What I´m trying to do:
-mazeygg.com/penis?kagNick=Mazey return ´gold player´
in the first js/jq part:
make the /penis.html**?kagNick=Nickname** (nickname = mazey, for example)
in the second part, php:
connect to the website
in the third part, js again:
split the website and print something (Check http://api.kag2d.com/player/mazey/status)

I chose this because I did not find a proper way to do the php part in JS (I code js, not php), if you know how: it´s really appreciated! If you do not: Help me fixing this code so I can move on.

Thanks, in advance

Comment: `$result` is a PHP variable on your server. `$result.split("/n")` in your user's browser will probably fail because `$result` is undefined in your script.

Comment: @lorenzo.marcon twice

Comment: Also are those penis urls just an unfortunate coincidence?

Comment: no I just always use penis for testing stuff, but whatever. How do I fix that, @Paulpro

Comment: shouldn't it be `\n` instead of `/n`? anyway, it looks like a kind of rough method to parse that json

Comment: Oh, okay. I thought maybe it was an abbreviation gone wrong or something haha.

Comment: Personally I use `foobar`, or some equivalent, but each to their own!

Comment: You have not updated the post to avoid spam terms. I'm in good faith reporting as spam until corrected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Bridge" from PHP to JS:

```
<script type="application/javascript" language="javascript">
var someVariableThatYouWantToGetFromPHP="<?=$PHPvariable?>";
</script>
```

When PHP has executed, there will be such an output HTML:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
var someVariableThatYouWantToGetFromPHP="wheeha! JS has got the value of PHP variable";
//and here later you are now able to use it
</script>
```

"Bridge" from JS to PHP is a little bit more complex. You can't just get *some* JS variable and put it in *some* PHP script at *some* time.
You have to make an HTTP request to the server with PHP.

That is exactly what forms do. If you have a form in your HTML code:

```
<form name="form1" action="phpscript.php" method="POST">
<input name="passingJSvarToPHP" type="hidden" value="" />
</form>
```

, then you may later submit the form from your JS code and this way pass any variable you want to your PHP script. JS code:

```
document.form1.passingJSvarToPHP.value=yourJSvariableThatYouWantToPutInYourPHPscript;
document.form1.submit();
```

And there is your PHP code on the server side, that will catch the variable:

```
<?php
$yeahGotTheJSvariable=$_POST['passingJSvarToPHP'];
//and here you may use your variable passed from JS code
?>
```

You have to understand, that when a form submit()s, the phpscript.php is then loaded instead of the page with the form.

You have to understand the synchronous request-response model of HTTP before writing such web applications, and before this, wait a bit with javascript. That will be level 1.

P. S. Level 2: AJAX.
P. P. S. Level 3: WebSockets.

Answer (score 3):

There are many things wrong with your code and the main problem is you are mixing PHP and JS code. For example:

```
$url = "https://api.kag2d.com/player/"+nick+"/status";
```

`nick` is a Javascript variable and you can't just mix it in PHP code.

The same problem for:

```
status = $result.split("/n")
```

where `$result` is PHP variable.

Comment: How do I make a bridge, or whatever? There must be a way to do it some how

Comment: PHP = Server side language. Javascript = Client side. They don't mix. They don't "bridge". They don't know or care about eachother. @Mazey, you need to read a book or three.

Comment: Yes you can do ajax and that's the only solution for your problem I think. Basically after you get that `nick`, do a GET request to that API page (use jsonp or code a bridge with PHP and curl) and then process the result in the response.

Comment: I dislike books, anyway. I´ll go for using ajax, I guess. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I see two things wrong with the file: 
 1. For you to include php in a file the file extension must have a .php extension 
 2. Variables are not shared for php and javascript. What you could do is use PHP's $_GET[]
array. For example:

```
<?php
$nick = $_GET['nick']
$url = "https://api.kag2d.com/player/".$nick."/status";
$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$result = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
$formattedresult = explode("/n",$result)
 if(strrpos($formattedresult,"true,") != -1)
 {
  echo "Gold player"
 }
?>
```